# Intercept the call to an async method using DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, reflection, aop, async-await, castle-dynamicproxy

Below is the code from the `Intercept` method on a custom type that implements `IInterceptor` of the [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) library. This snippet is from an [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) based logging proof-of-concept console app that is posted [here](https://github.com/floydpink/LoggerPoc).

```
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled) Log.Debug(CreateInvocationLogString("Called", invocation));
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                if (invocation.Method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                    Log.Debug("Returning with: " + invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Log.IsErrorEnabled) Log.Error(CreateInvocationLogString("ERROR", invocation), ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is working as expected on regular method calls, but not when tried with `async` methods (using the `async/await` keywords from C# 5.0). And I believe, I understand the reasons behind this as well.

For the `async/await` to work, the compiler adds the functional body of the method into a state machine behind the scenes and the control will return to the caller, as soon as the first `awaitable` expression that cannot be completed synchronously, is encountered.

Also, we can interrogate the return type and figure out whether we are dealing with an `async` method like this:

```
            if (invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(Task) || 
                (invocation.Method.ReturnType.IsGenericType && 
                 invocation.Method.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>)))
                Log.Info("Asynchronous method found...");
```

This works for only those `async` methods that returns either `Task` or `Task<>` and not `void` but I am fine with that.

What changes have to made within the `Intercept` method so that the `awaiter` would return to there rather than the original caller?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Presumably the "problem" is that it's just logging that it's returning a task - and you want the *value* within that task?

Assuming that's the case, you still have to return the task to the caller, immediately - without waiting for it to complete. If you break that, you're fundamentally messing things up.

However, before you return the task to the caller, you should add a continuation (via [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx)) which will log the result (or failure) *when the task completes*. That will still give the result information, but of course you'll be logging it potentially after some other logging. You may *also* want to log immediately before returning, leading to a log something like this:

```
Called FooAsync
Returned from FooAsync with a task
Task from FooAsync completed, with return value 5
```

The business of getting the result out of the task (if it completed successfully) would have to be done with reflection, which is a bit of a pain - or you could use dynamic typing. (Either way it will be a bit of a performance hit.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was definitely looking for `ContinueWith`. And yes, I want the interceptor to continue logging the return value and any exceptions within.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to Jon's answer, this is what I ended up with:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    if (Log.IsDebugEnabled) Log.Debug(CreateInvocationLogString("Called", invocation));
    try
    {
        invocation.Proceed();

        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
            if (returnType != typeof(void))
            {
                var returnValue = invocation.ReturnValue;
                if (returnType == typeof(Task))
                {
                    Log.Debug("Returning with a task.");
                }
                else if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
                {
                    Log.Debug("Returning with a generic task.");
                    var task = (Task)returnValue;
                    task.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
                                          {
                                              var taskDescriptor = CreateInvocationLogString("Task from", invocation);
                                              var result =
                                                  antecedent.GetType()
                                                            .GetProperty("Result")
                                                            .GetValue(antecedent, null);
                                              Log.Debug(taskDescriptor + " returning with: " + result);
                                          });
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Debug("Returning with: " + returnValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Log.IsErrorEnabled) Log.Error(CreateInvocationLogString("ERROR", invocation), ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the implemented solution, it's good to know not just what guidance Jon Skeet gave, but how you took that and applied it.

Comment: Something interesting to note: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute.aspx -- This attribute can be probed to determine if the method is marked async or not, instead of relying on the return type to be a typeof `Task` or `Task<T>`...

Answer (score 10):

Trying to clarify with a generic and clean solution for:

- Intercepting `async` methods adding custom code as a continuation task.

I think the best solution is to use the `dynamic` keyword to bypass the compiler type checking and resolve the difference between Task and Task`<T>` at run time:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    invocation.Proceed();
    var method = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
    var isAsync = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute)) != null;
    if (isAsync && typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType))
    {
        invocation.ReturnValue = InterceptAsync((dynamic)invocation.ReturnValue);
    }
}

private static async Task InterceptAsync(Task task)
{
    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    // do the logging here, as continuation work for Task...
}

private static async Task<T> InterceptAsync<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    T result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    // do the logging here, as continuation work for Task<T>...
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents:

It has been correctly established that for `async` methods the purpose of the interceptor would be to **"enhance" the task returned** by the invocation, via a continuation.

Now, **it is precisely this task continuation the one that has to be returned** to make the job of the interceptor complete.

So, based on the above discussions and examples, this would work perfectly well for regular methods as well as "raw" `async Task` methods.

```
public virtual void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    try
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        var task = invocation.ReturnValue as Task;
        if (task != null)
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = task.ContinueWith(t => {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                    OnException(invocation, t.Exception);
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnException(invocation, ex);
    }
}

public virtual void OnException(IInvocation invocation, Exception exception)
{
    ...
}
```

1. But when dealing with `async Task<T>` methods, the above would incorrectly change the type of the task returned by the interception, from `Task<T>` to regular `Task`
2. Notice that we are calling `Task.ContinueWith()` and not `Task<TResult>.ContinueWith()`, which is the method we want to call.

This would be the resulting exception when ultimately awaiting the such an interception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1

Comment: Hi. I am trying to implement solution that works correct with methods that returns Task<T> result, the issue is that I can't cast to appropriate type dynamically. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Changing the return value is a mistake. Removing the `invocation.ReturnValue = ` and  just adding a ContinueWith on the task makes this work fine for both Task and Task<T> as you are just adding a continueWIth onto both, not trying to set what the original ReturnValue was which of course will error if you try and set it to a Task when it was a Task<T>

Answer (score 4):

Below is my async interceptor adapter implementation that correctly handles async methods.

```
abstract class AsyncInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    class TaskCompletionSourceMethodMarkerAttribute : Attribute
    {

    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo _taskCompletionSourceMethod = typeof(AsyncInterceptor)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Single(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TaskCompletionSourceMethodMarkerAttribute)).Any());


    protected virtual Task<Object> InterceptAsync(Object target, MethodBase method, object[] arguments, Func<Task<Object>> proceed)
    {
        return proceed();
    }

    protected virtual void Intercept(Object target, MethodBase method, object[] arguments, Action proceed)
    {
        proceed();
    }

    [TaskCompletionSourceMethodMarker]
    Task<TResult> TaskCompletionSource<TResult>(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();

        var task = InterceptAsync(invocation.InvocationTarget, invocation.Method, invocation.Arguments, () =>
        {
            var task2 = (Task)invocation.Method.Invoke(invocation.InvocationTarget, invocation.Arguments);
            var tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();
            task2.ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs2.SetException(x.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                dynamic dynamicTask = task2;
                Object result = dynamicTask.Result;
                tcs2.SetResult(result);
            });
            return tcs2.Task;
        });

        task.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            if (x.IsFaulted)
            {
                tcs.SetException(x.Exception);
                return;
            }

            tcs.SetResult((TResult)x.Result);
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
    void IInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (!typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(invocation.Method.ReturnType))
        {
            Intercept(invocation.InvocationTarget, invocation.Method, invocation.Arguments, invocation.Proceed);
            return;
        }
        var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType.IsGenericType ? invocation.Method.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0] : typeof(object);
        var method = _taskCompletionSourceMethod.MakeGenericMethod(returnType);
        invocation.ReturnValue = method.Invoke(this, new object[] { invocation });
    }
}
```

and sample usage:

```
class TestInterceptor : AsyncInterceptor
{
    protected override async Task<Object> InterceptAsync(object target, MethodBase method, object[] arguments, Func<Task<object>> proceed)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var result = await proceed();
        return DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2 == 0 ? 10000 :result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a need to intercept methods returning `Task<TResult>`, I've created an extension to `Castle.Core` that simplifies the process.

[Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor)

The package is available to download on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor).

The solution is largely based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28374134) from [@silas-reinagel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009517/silas-reinagel), but simplifies it by providing a new interface to implement [IAsyncInterceptor](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor#option-1--implement-iasyncinterceptor-interface-to-intercept-invocations). There are also further abstractions to that make interception similar to implementing `Interceptor`.

See the [readme](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor#castlecoreasyncinterceptor) of the project for further details.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    void IInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
>        try {
>            invocation.Proceed();
>            var task = invocation.ReturnValue as Task;
>            if (task != null && task.IsFaulted) throw task.Exception;
>        }
>        catch {
>            throw;
>        }
>    }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
tcs2.SetException(x.Exception);
```

You should use:

```
x.Exception.Handle(ex => { tcs2.SetException(ex); return true; });
```

to bubble up the real exception...