# Intercept async method that returns generic Task<> via DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, castle-dynamicproxy

My questions is related to this post [Intercept the call to an async method using DynamicProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288075/intercept-the-call-to-an-async-method-using-dynamicproxy)

I want to implement interceptor that works with async methods that returns `Task` or `Task<T>` result.

I use next code for return `ContinueWith` result (in order that caller method wait while interceptor finishes work)

```
var task = invocation.ReturnValue as Task;
invocation.ReturnValue = task.ContinueWith(c => 
      { code that should execute after method finish });
```

Above code works fine for `Task` result, but in case of `Task<T>` result `ContinueWith` will change return type from `Task<T>` to `Task`.
I need to call overloaded method ContinueWith that returns `Task<T>`, but for this I need to cast `invocation.ReturnValue` to `Task<T>`

I didn't find way to cast it dynamically in any way. 
Does anyone know how to make it?

I also tried to call this method via reflection, but parameter is labmda function that can't be passed directly.

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574805.aspx - article is for Unity interceptors, but "wrap the task" code does not depend on your DI container.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After extensive research, I was able to create a solution that works for intercepting Synchronous Methods as well as Async Task and Async Task< TResult >.

Here is my code for an Exception Handling interceptor that works on all those method types, using Castle Dynamic Proxy. This pattern is adaptable for doing any sort of intercept you wish. The syntax will be a little cleaner for standard BeforeInvoke/AfterInvoke actions, but the concept should be the same.

(Other note: the IExceptionHandler interface in the example is a custom type, and not a common object.)

```
    private class AsyncExceptionHandlingInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo handleAsyncMethodInfo = typeof(AsyncExceptionHandlingInterceptor).GetMethod("HandleAsyncWithResult", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        private readonly IExceptionHandler _handler;

        public AsyncExceptionHandlingInterceptor(IExceptionHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var delegateType = GetDelegateType(invocation);
            if (delegateType == MethodType.Synchronous)
            {
                _handler.HandleExceptions(() => invocation.Proceed());
            }
            if (delegateType == MethodType.AsyncAction)
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
                invocation.ReturnValue = HandleAsync((Task)invocation.ReturnValue);
            }
            if (delegateType == MethodType.AsyncFunction)
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
                ExecuteHandleAsyncWithResultUsingReflection(invocation);
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteHandleAsyncWithResultUsingReflection(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var resultType = invocation.Method.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var mi = handleAsyncMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(resultType);
            invocation.ReturnValue = mi.Invoke(this, new[] { invocation.ReturnValue });
        }

        private async Task HandleAsync(Task task)
        {
            await _handler.HandleExceptions(async () => await task);
        }

        private async Task<T> HandleAsyncWithResult<T>(Task<T> task)
        {
            return await _handler.HandleExceptions(async () => await task);
        }

        private MethodType GetDelegateType(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
            if (returnType == typeof(Task))
                return MethodType.AsyncAction;
            if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
                return MethodType.AsyncFunction;
            return MethodType.Synchronous;
        }

        private enum MethodType
        {
            Synchronous,
            AsyncAction,
            AsyncFunction
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this, it was exactly what I was looking for.  Just so it's clear for others, here's the IExceptionHandler interface methods.  In my implementation I actually renamed these classes to be generic for use in any interceptor that may intercept async methods.  `void Handle(Action synchronousInvoker)`, `Task Handle(Func<Task> awaitableInvoker)`, `Task<T> Handle<T>(Func<Task<T>> awaitableInvoker)`.

Comment: I see that 'HandleAsyncWithResult' method is never called. Did you forgot something in sample code? I see that in case of 'AsyncFunction' exceptions won't be handled.

Comment: The 'HandleAsyncWithResult' method is called in a roundabout fashion from the 'ExecuteHandleAsyncWithResultUsingReflection' method. The exceptions are handled by the .NET Task objects, and correctly thrown when invoked.

Answer (score 17):

A better solution would be to use the `dynamic` keyword to bypass the compiler type checking and resolve the operation at run time:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    invocation.Proceed();
    var method = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
    var isAsync = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute)) != null;
    if (isAsync && typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType))
    {
        invocation.ReturnValue = InterceptAsync((dynamic)invocation.ReturnValue);
    }
}

private static async Task InterceptAsync(Task task)
{
    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    // do the continuation work for Task...
}

private static async Task<T> InterceptAsync<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    T result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    // do the continuation work for Task<T>...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this is a much more concise solution!

Comment: Why do you think this condition `typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType)` is not enough to proceed handling the async interception?

Comment: It's a great idea. I created a help package with the help of it ,thanks.Ones who need it please visit:<https://github.com/wswind/lightwind/blob/master/src/Lightwind.AsyncInterceptor/AsyncInterceptorBase.cs>

Answer (score 7):

Having a need to intercept methods returning `Task<TResult>`, I've created an extension to `Castle.Core` that simplifies the process.

[Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor)

The package is available to download on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor).

The solution is largely based on the answer from [@silas-reinagel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009517/silas-reinagel), but simplifies it by providing a new interface to implement [IAsyncInterceptor](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor#option-1--implement-iasyncinterceptor-interface-to-intercept-invocations). There are also further abstractions to that make interception similar to implementing `Interceptor`.

See the [readme](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor#castlecoreasyncinterceptor) of the project for further details.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions from @Silas Reinagel and @thepirat000 didn't work for me, and I was not successful using `Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor` solution from @James Skimming.

In my case, I'm intercepting an async method returning `Task`, and it should execute "after invocation.Proceed() code" only if there was no exception during the `invocation.Proceed()`. At the end I used @James Skimming's [code sample](https://github.com/JSkimming/Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor#methods-that-return-task), so this solution works only for intercepting async methods returning `Task` and not `Task<TResult>`:

```cs
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    _stepPriorInvocation();

    invocation.Proceed();
    Func<Task> continuation = async () =>
    {
        await (Task)invocation.ReturnValue;

        _stepAfterSuccessfulInvocation();
    };

    invocation.ReturnValue = continuation();

    void _stepPriorInvocation()
    {
    }

    void _stepAfterSuccessfulInvocation()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done this way:

```
invocation.Proceed(); 
object response;
Type type = invocation.ReturnValue?.GetType();
if (type != null && typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(type))
{
    var resultProperty = type.GetProperty("Result");
    response = resultProperty.GetValue(invocation.ReturnValue);
}
```