# Autofac Interception async execution order

Tags: c#, async-await, autofac, interception

So I have this class:

```
public class MappingBootstrap : IMappingBootstrap
{
    public virtual async Task Map()
    {
        // Order is very important

        await this.mapper1.Map();

        await this.mapper2.Map();

        await this.mapper3.Map();

        await this.mapper4.Map();
    }
}
```

I have Autofac Interceptor:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodReference = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling {invocation?.Method?.DeclaringType?.Name}.{invocation?.Method?.Name} : {methodReference}");

        var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        invocation?.Proceed();

        startNew.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"{methodReference} : Done, time taken: {startNew.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}
```

This produces the output:

> Calling IMapperBootstrap.Map : 54425559-71fe-4f23-ab47-d0f3371ec819 
>    Calling IMapper1.Map : 51babb34-fa83-42ed-84e7-a1e979528116 
>    51babb34-fa83-42ed-84e7-a1e979528116 : Done, time taken: 219ms 
>    54425559-71fe-4f23-ab47-d0f3371ec819 : Done, time taken: 221ms 
>    Calling IMapper2.Map : 41c812a2-d82d-48f6-9b8d-139b52eb28e3 
>    41c812a2-d82d-48f6-9b8d-139b52eb28e3 : Done, time taken: 9ms 
>    Calling IMapper3.Map : c91bed04-8f86-47d3-a35a-417e354c2c5f 
>    c91bed04-8f86-47d3-a35a-417e354c2c5f : Done, time taken: 994ms 
>    Calling IMapper4.Map : 035cad27-1ba8-4bd1-b85f-396f64998d97 
>    035cad27-1ba8-4bd1-b85f-396f64998d97 : Done, time taken: 18ms

As you can see, the `MappingBoostrap.Map` finishes after the first `Mapper1.Map` rather than what I expect which is when all the functions have completed. **Why?**

---

Autofac Config:

```
builder.Register(context => new LoggingInterceptor());

builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly)
    .Where(x => x.Namespace.Contains("Mapping"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggingInterceptor));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why?

When you call an asynchronous method like this:

```
mapping.Map();
```

it only *starts* the method. This is [how asynchronous methods work](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as I explain on my blog). If you `await` the task returned by the asynchronous method, then the current method will pause until the asynchronous method completes:

```
await mapping.Map();
```

In the case of *interception*, the *ideal* solution would be to have the `Proceed` and `Intercept` methods asynchronous:

```
public async Task InterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation)
{
  ...
  await invocation?.ProceedAsync();
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, Autofac has no built-in understanding of asynchronous methods, so this isn't possible. Instead, you have to call `Proceed`, which just *starts* the asynchronous method. The asynchronous method returns a `Task`, which represents the execution of that method. To hook into the completion of the method, you should *replace* that `Task` with one of your own.

For a plain `Task`-returning method, you can use something like this:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
  var methodReference = Guid.NewGuid();
  Console.WriteLine($"Calling {invocation?.Method?.DeclaringType?.Name}.{invocation?.Method?.Name} : {methodReference}");

  var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();

  invocation.Proceed();
  invocation.ReturnValue = WatchAsync(methodReference, startNew, (Task)invocation.ReturnValue);
}

private static async Task WatchAsync(Guid methodReference,
    Stopwatch stopwatch, Task methodExecution)
{
  try
  {
    await methodExecution.ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
  finally
  {
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{methodReference} : Done, time taken: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering whether that was the reason, but some part of me said why would Autofac not support `await/async`, but this seems like a simple solution. The thing is do you want to have the interception handle how you  await `Task`s or the code where the actual invocation is taking place. I guess it's one of those things that you have to bear in mind when intercepting asynchronous code.

Comment: @CallumLinington: To be clear, the code being intercepted should still use `await`. The intercepting code just intercepts the returned `Task` and replaces it with one of its own (which happens to be implemented with `async`/`await`).

Comment: Note the interception is done by Castle.DynamicProxy, not Autofac. Autofac just makes wiring it up easier.

Comment: Just as an FYI @StephenCleary the `WatchAsync` method is called with an incorrect number of parameters

Comment: Am I correct this approach will fail if invocation returned task has parameters? If so, what we can do if we don't want to write code for each possible invoked method?

Comment: Yes, and here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099669/intercept-async-method-that-returns-generic-task-via-dynamicproxy