# Possible to intercept an async method and overwrite ReturnValue?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, interceptor

I have a method:

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req) {
  return OkObjectResult(null);
}
```

I know I can intercept this synchronously using autofac:

```
public class CallLogger : IInterceptor
{
  TextWriter _output;

  public CallLogger(TextWriter output)
  {
    _output = output;
  }

 public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
    _output.Write("Calling method {0} with parameters {1}... ",
      invocation.Method.Name,
      string.Join(", ", invocation.Arguments.Select(a => (a ?? "").ToString()).ToArray()));

    invocation.Proceed();

    _output.WriteLine("Done: result was {0}.", invocation.ReturnValue);
  }
}
```

But how can I do this asynchronously while potentially overwriting the result the method I'm intercepting returns? It currently returns an `OkObjectResult`, I may want to return a 404 instead, for example.

### Psuedo Code

```
public async Task Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    var myAsyncResult = await _myAsyncClass.MyAsyncMethod();

    if (myAsyncResult == expected)
    {
       invocation.Proceed();
    }
    else
    {
       invocation.ReturnValue = // some overwrite of the value - and don't proceed with the invocation.
    }
}
```

### Note

I know there are clever approaches to async in autofac, but this doesn't allow me to prevent execution of the original method and overwrite the value, instead I need to 'proceed' the invocation and use it's return: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784559/12683473

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to keep in mind with Castle.Core is that you cannot call `IInvocation.Proceed` after an `await` because the `IInvocation` instance is reused after the interceptor (synchronously) returns.

However, modern versions of Castle.Core do support `IInvocation.CaptureProceedInfo`, which can be used as such:

```
public class CallLogger : IInterceptor
{
  public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
    invocation.ReturnValue = InterceptAsync<MyResult>(invocation.CaptureProceedInfo());
  }

  private async Task<TResult> InterceptAsync<TResult>(IInvocationProceedInfo proceed)
  {
    var myAsyncResult = await _myAsyncClass.MyAsyncMethod();

    if (myAsyncResult == expected)
    {
      proceed.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
      return ...;
    }
  }
}
```

This simple code assumes your code can specify a type `MyResult` that is the known result of the intercepted method. The more general case [requires reflection and `TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/db192c085e43c4750ec3cc7678a8c55b6bd59121/docs/dynamicproxy-async-interception.md#intercepting-awaitable-methods-that-produce-a-return-value).

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate! Much appreciated. I'm confused, though - not all of those code paths return a value. I'm assuming my `return ...;` is my overwrite (i.e. the value the original invocation wouldn't have returned, it's some value I'm returning on the fly). But how do I return the value from the original invocation if necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Good catch; I did do that wrong. You'd need to pass `IInvocation` in to `InterceptAsync` and then use `ReturnValue` (cast to `Task<TResult>`) after the `Invoke`. See the [source of `AsyncInterceptor` for details](https://github.com/stakx/DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptor).