I can't run LogAspect using Castle DynamicProxy
I am using an Interceptors structure created with Castle DynamicProxy in the project and I wrote a LogAspect for logging operations. However, LogAspect is not triggered in any way. I am sharing my codes below. I am waiting for your help on what the problem may be or what adjustments I need to make to run it correctly.
namespace ebordro.Interceptors
{
    //kullanılacak tüm interceptionların temel sınıfı
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public abstract class MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute : Attribute, IInterceptor
    {
        public int Priority { get; set; } //verilen sırada çalışması için.

        public virtual void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace ebordro.Interceptors
{
    //metotlarlarda kullanılacak olan interception işlemleri için temel sınıf.
    public class MethodInterception : MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute
    {
        protected virtual void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation) { }
        protected virtual void OnAfter(IInvocation invocation) { }
        protected virtual void OnException(IInvocation invocation, Exception e) { }
        protected virtual void OnSuccess(IInvocation invocation) { }


        public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var isSuccess = true;
            OnBefore(invocation);
            try
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                OnException(invocation, e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (isSuccess)
                {
                    OnSuccess(invocation);
                }
            }

            OnAfter(invocation);
        }
    }

}

namespace ebordro.Interceptors
{
    //hangi interceptor'ların uygulanacağını seçer.
    public class AspectInterceptorSelector : IInterceptorSelector
    {
        public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type type, MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
        {
            var classAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes<MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute>(true).ToList();
            var methodAttributes = type.GetMethod(method.Name).GetCustomAttributes<MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute>(true);
            classAttributes.AddRange(methodAttributes);

            return classAttributes.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToArray();

        }
    }
}

namespace ebordro.Interceptors.Aspects
{
    public class LogAspect : MethodInterception
    {
        private readonly IActionLogService _actionLogService;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public LogAspect()
        {
            var serviceProvider = ServiceToolForAspect.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
            _actionLogService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionLogService>();
            _httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        }
        protected override void OnAfter(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            using (var scope = ServiceToolForAspect.serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var actionLogService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionLogService>();
                using (var scope = ServiceToolForAspect.CreateScope())
                {
                    var actionLogService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionLogService>();

                    var httpContextAccessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

                    var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

                    string usermail = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                    int userId = 0;
                    int companyId = 0;

                    if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        var userIdClaim = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                        if (userIdClaim != null)
                        {
                            userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
                        }

                        var companyIdClaim = httpContext.User.FindFirst("CompanyId");
                        if (companyIdClaim != null)
                        {
                            companyId = int.Parse(companyIdClaim.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    İşlem detayını oluştur
                   var processDetail = CreateProcessDetail(invocation);

                    Loglama işlemini gerçekleştir
                    actionLogService.AddLogRecordAsync(userId, usermail, companyId, invocation.Method.Name.ToUpper(), processDetail)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false)
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();
                }
                var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

                var usermail = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                var userId = 0;
                var companyId = 0;

                var processDetail = CreateProcessDetail(invocation);

                if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var userIdClaim = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                    if (userIdClaim != null)
                    {
                        userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
                    }

                    var companyIdClaim = httpContext.User.FindFirst("CompanyId");
                    if (companyIdClaim != null)
                    {
                        companyId = int.Parse(companyIdClaim.Value);
                    }
                }

                //_actionLogService.AddLogRecordAsync(userId,usermail,companyId,invocation.Method.Name.ToUpper(),processDetail).Wait();
                _actionLogService.AddLogRecordAsync(userId, usermail, companyId, invocation.Method.Name.ToUpper(), processDetail).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            }

            private string CreateProcessDetail(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var methodName = invocation.Method.Name;
            var arguments = invocation.Arguments;

            string message = $"{methodName} metodu çağrıldı. Parametreler: ";

            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Length; i++)
            {
                message += $"Parametre {i + 1}: {arguments[i]?.ToString() ?? "null"}; ";
            }

            return message;
        }


    }
}


[LogAspect]
        public async Task AddLogRecordAsync(int userId, string stringValue, int? intValue, string process, string processDetail)
        {
            ...codes...
        }


What I Tried:

I created an interception structure with Castle DynamicProxy and defined a class called LogAspect for logging operations.
I specified LogAspect as an attribute derived from the MethodInterceptionBaseAttribute class.
I collected the attributes assigned to methods or classes with the AspectInterceptorSelector class and aimed to run them in the specified order.
I solved the dependencies using the DI container with ServiceToolForAspect.

What I Expected:

When the GetAllActionLogAsync method is called, LogAspect will come into play and perform the logging operations by running the OnBefore, OnAfter, or other interception methods.

What Actually Happened:

LogAspect is not running at all. The methods do not seem to pass through interception. The logging codes I wrote inside the method do not work and I do not receive any error messages.


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Would may be this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099669/intercept-async-method-that-returns-generic-task-via-dynamicproxy ?
